# How to display different content for 15 days in a loop with Javascript Vanilla?

Tags: javascript

I need to display different content for 15 days in a loop indefinitely with JavaScript Vanilla.  So each day, I display a div with specific content and after 15 days, the process starts. Here is what I have done so far:

```
const Rotator = {

    init(startDate) {
        const todayMonth = new Date(SERVER_DATETIME).getMonth() + 1;
        const todayDate = new Date(SERVER_DATETIME).getDate();
        const sectionArray = [];//array of ids
        const daysArray = [];//array of days to rotate

        document.querySelectorAll('.ws-slide').forEach((item,index) => {
            let id = item.id;
            sectionArray.push(id);
        });
        // console.log(sectionArray);
        sectionArray.forEach((item, index) => {
            daysArray.push(startDate + (index * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        });
        // console.log(daysArray);

        daysArray.forEach((item, index) => {
            let newMonth = new Date(item).getMonth() + 1;
            let newDate = new Date(item).getDate();

            if (newMonth === todayMonth && newDate === todayDate) {
                console.log(sectionArray[index])
                document.querySelector(`#${sectionArray[0]}`).style.display = "none";
                document.querySelector(`#${sectionArray[index]}`).style.display = 'block';
            } 
        });



    }
}
```

The script takes the start date and creates two arrays: one for the ids of the element and the other for the next 15 days in milliseconds.  I'm able to execute the script for 15 days, but don't know how to restart the cycle dynamically unless I set up different start dates. Below I set up the restart date every 15 days for the first 90 days:

```
const spectrumStartDate = '6/29/2023';
        let date;
        let d = new Date(SERVER_DATETIME);
        let slidesLength = document.querySelectorAll('.ws-slide').length;
        let cycle = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * slidesLength;

        let mydate = new Date(spectrumStartDate).getTime(); //'6/29'
        console.log("start date 6/29 " + new Date(mydate));
        let mydate15 = mydate + cycle;
        console.log("start date 7/14 " + new Date(mydate15));
        let mydate30 = mydate15 + cycle;
        console.log("start date 7/29 " + new Date(mydate30));
        let mydate45 = mydate30 + cycle;
        console.log("start date 8/13 " + new Date(mydate45));
        let mydate60 = mydate45 + cycle;
        console.log("start date 8/28 " + new Date(mydate60));
        let mydate75 = mydate60 + cycle;
        console.log("start date 9/12 " + new Date(mydate75));
        let mydate90 = mydate75 + cycle;
        console.log("start date 9/27 " + new Date(mydate90));

        if (d >= mydate90) {
            date = mydate90 //start date is 9/27
        } else if (d >= mydate75) {
            date = mydate75 //start date is 9/12
        } else if (d >= mydate60) {
            date = mydate60 //start date is 8/28
        } else if (d >= mydate45) {
            date = mydate45 //start date is 8/13
        } else if (d >= mydate30) {
            date = mydate30 //start date is 7/29
        } else if (d >= mydate15) {
            date = mydate15; //start date is 7/14
        } else if (d >= mydate) {
            date = mydate;//start date is 6/29
        }

        console.log("start date is " + new Date(date));

        Rotator.init(date);
```

I'd greatly appreciate it if you could help me.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get number of days from 1970 and get a remainder of `15`. Adjust to your start date offset if needed:

```js
// get number of days from 1970 in local time
const day = (new Date(new Date().toDateString()).getTime()/60/1000 - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset()))/60/24
// get your day index from 0 to 14
console.log(day % 15);
```

More verbose:

```js
// get number of days from 1970 in local time
const now = new Date;
const todayUTC = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
let minutes = todayUTC.getTime()/60/* seconds *//1000; // milliseconds
// fix timezone offset (minutes);
minutes -= now.getTimezoneOffset();
// calc day
const day = minutes/60 /*minutes*//24; //hours
// get your day index from 0 to 14
console.log(day % 15);
```

Comment: -Thank you.  Makes sense, but I would loop it?

Comment: @mgreen no need, it loops itself, when it reaches 14 the next day it becomes 0. if you need 1-15 range just add 1 to it. if you find my answer useful please don't hesitate to accept it (the checkbox) and upvote (the arrow up), that way i'll be motivated to help you in the future, thanks

Comment: Thankyou, Alexander, I got it. I was testing it before responding to make sure.

Comment: @mgreen what is the result? working for you? if so could you accept (the checkbox)?

Comment: I checked your comment.  Is this what you meant by accepting the checkbox?

Comment: nope, the checkbox on the answer, like you accept my answer as a solution to your question

Comment: Thank you, I checked it.  Your solution worked really well!

Comment: @mgreen that's really encouraging, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need a JS-only solution, you can store the value of the first date in the [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) and a value initialized to 1 that will count the elapsed days. Every time the user enters the website, it will have to be verified if the system (or server) date is greater than or equal to the stored date ([get the date difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15289883/3689977)); if it's greater, then the old date is replaced by the current one and the count of days will be increased by 1. At the same time, it would check if the count of days is greater, less or equal to 15; if it's greater, the account is reset, otherwise its value will be increased by 1. And while the account remains less than or equal to 15, a different content will be displayed for each day, which may also be stored locally (or in a server) in the form of an array of objects, where each one would correspond to the count of days (minus 1, considering that the arrays start from position 0).

Either way, it would be better with a backend-only solution or just use [Cron Jobs](https://www.hivelocity.net/kb/what-is-cron-job/).

Comment: Thank you, @Alexis88 - I would need to display different content each day for all users; so local storage wouldn't work.

Comment: @mgreen Just apply same or similar logic but on server side. It'd be better and safer than do this just with JS.